# Hyperlink text with Attributed String in UILable

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want to show hyperlink with text by using Attributed string in `UILabel`.

I have search for that but not getting any proper result.

Is it possible to show text with hyperlink using attributed string in `UILabel`?

Can anyone guide me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) 
Import their library into your project. And then:

Import these classes in your ViewController

```
#import <NSAttributedString+HTML.h>
#import <DTCoreText/DTCoreTextConstants.h>
```

And do something like:

```
NSData *HTMLData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *optionsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], DTUseiOS6Attributes,  @"your-fontName" ,  DTDefaultFontFamily, @(12), DTDefaultFontSize, nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:HTMLData options:optionsDictionary documentAttributes:nil];

[infoBodyLabel setAttributedText:attrString];
```

And you're done!